# Webrtc working fine on same network but not working when one of device on wifi and other device on mobile data

Tags: webrtc, signaling

Webrtc working fine on same network(same wifi) but not working when one of device on wifi and other device on mobile data.Its saying "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Error processing ICE candidate".

Please help

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup. What are you using for signalling? Are you in an app, or on the browser? Are you using https?

Comment: @Mikkel I am using NodeJs as signalling server, I have mobile app(Hybrid app) from there I am calling to a website, running on PC .Normally it works fine when we are on same network,but when I am switching to mobile data and calling to website then this issue comes... Please see this screen https://postimg.org/image/n64kojik7/

Comment: Nodejs isn't a signalling server. You must be using a package, or some code from the webrtc web site. Edit the question to show the code please

Comment: I am using following code https://github.com/dimircea/WebRTC/tree/master/SimpleVideoChat

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Try making your connection **HTTPS**

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.